# oncontextmenu not working when append rows in HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, contextmenu, right-click

i am fetching 70 records from database and loading it in html table and when user scroll down from 1 to 70th record, on scroll event call and next 70 fetched e.g **limit 70, 140** record fetched and append to already displayed records.
so that i also using right click or oncontextmenu function in all rows by adding a class.
when user right click in any data row of table on('contextmenu',function(){}); event called in first 70 records that fetched by default but not called on  next 70 records which comes after scroll and appended with first 70 records.
please help me to solve this why on contextmenu event not called up??
my code is.

//first 70 records comes as by default and display in table rows as

```
echo '<tr class="mute_ref_link_cls" id="' . $mm->msn . '_' . str_replace(array('_dup', '-dup'), '', $mm->name) . '_' . $mm->customer_id . '"  onClick="mute_ctrl_fn(' . $mm->customer_id . ');openSubDiv(' . $mm->cid . ',' . $mm->customer_id . ',\'' . $mm->f_id . '\',\'' . $mm->msn . '\',\'info\',\'' . str_replace(array('_dup', '-dup'), '', $mm->name) . '\');">';
echo '<td class="muteClr with-tip" id="' . $mm->customer_id . '" title="' . $res . '"><a style="color:red" onClick="">' . str_replace('-dup', '', str_replace('_dup', '', $mm->name)) . '</a></td>';
echo '<td>';
echo ($mm->session_date_time > 0) ? date('d-M-Y H:i', strtotime($mm->session_date_time)) : 'N/A';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

**After scroll next 70 records fetched and append at the end of 70th record as

```
echo '<tr class="mute_ref_link_cls" id="'.$mm->msn.'_'.str_replace(array('_dup','-dup'), '', $mm->name).'_'.$mm->customer_id.'"  onClick="mute_ctrl_fn('.$mm->customer_id.');openSubDiv('.$mm->cid.','.$mm->customer_id.',\''.$mm->f_id.'\',\''.$mm->msn.'\',\'info\',\''.str_replace(array('_dup','-dup'), '', $mm->name).'\');">';
        echo '<td class="muteClr with-tip" id="'.$mm->customer_id.'"  title="'.$res.'"><a style="color:red" onClick="">'.str_replace('-dup', '', str_replace('_dup', '', $mm->name)).'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo ($mm->session_date_time>0)?date('d-M-Y H:i',  strtotime($mm->session_date_time)):'N/A';
        echo '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
```

My jquery code when right click on any first 70 record:

```
$('.mute_ref_link_cls').on('contextMenu', function (event, list)
{
    $(this).trigger('click');
    var str = this.id;
    //getting msn and reference number as id on right click :: Ahmad Fraz
    var dtz = str.split("_");
    list.push({text: 'Add Reason', link: 'javascript:matchMMPinCodeForm(' + dtz[0] + ',' + dtz[1] + ',' + dtz[2] + ')', icon: 'blog'});
    list.push({text: 'Cancel', link: 'javascript:pending(' + dtz[0] + ',' + dtz[1] + ',' + dtz[2] + ',\'nf503698\')', icon: 'delete'});
});
```

Comment: Please use Event delegation of jQuery. Can you please mention the table class or Id so that I can post a snippet for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should use Event delegation for event binding on elements that get dynamically added to the DOM.

In your case it should be :

```
$('table').on('contextMenu', '.mute_ref_link_cls', function (event, list)
{
    $(this).trigger('click');
    var str = this.id;
    //getting msn and reference number as id on right click :: Ahmad Fraz
    var dtz = str.split("_");
    list.push({text: 'Add Reason', link: 'javascript:matchMMPinCodeForm(' + dtz[0] + ',' + dtz[1] + ',' + dtz[2] + ')', icon: 'blog'});
    list.push({text: 'Cancel', link: 'javascript:pending(' + dtz[0] + ',' + dtz[1] + ',' + dtz[2] + ',\'nf503698\')', icon: 'delete'});
});
```

As per the jQuery docs : http://api.jquery.com/on/

The 1st parameter is the event
2nd optional one is the selector
3rd optional one is the data for the handler
And the last is the handler for the event.

Sorry for the typos / code-alignment as I'm replying from my handheld device.

Comment: i need one more help... about database !! will you??

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes sure.

Comment: My software using mysql database which contains billion of records therefore queries going slow day by day. How i can handle this database to optimized response. Database data will raise day by day infinitely...

Comment: You have to optimize your queries I guess and add some indexing to your tables. Though I'm not an expert in that, I would suggest you to post specific queries here in SO so that experts may have a look at it and help you out in optimizing them. Figure out which queries are taking too long to execute and optimize them :).

Comment: Dear i think no issue in queries it's happening due to massive data in database.

Comment: Use table partitioning then and/or indexing. Please post specific questions here in SO. Respective experts will surely get your problem resolved :).